# Keep getting MySQLi Error

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

When I'm trying to connect to MySQLi, I keep getting this error:

```
Warning: mysqli::mysqli() [mysqli.mysqli]: (HY000/1105): (proxy) all backends are down in /home/xylotk/public_html/Main/Header.php on line 5

Warning: mysqli::real_escape_string() [mysqli.real-escape-string]: Couldn't fetch mysqli in /home/xylotk/public_html/Main/Logged.php on line 5

Warning: mysqli::real_escape_string() [mysqli.real-escape-string]: Couldn't fetch mysqli in /home/xylotk/public_html/Main/Logged.php on line 6

Warning: mysqli::query() [mysqli.query]: Couldn't fetch mysqli in /home/xylotk/public_html/Main/Logged.php on line 7

Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch_array() on a non-object in /home/xylotk/public_html/Main/Logged.php on line 8
```

I have no clue why this happens.
I've tried everything to fix it.

Can anyone atleast explain to me what this means?
This is what is causing the error:

```
 global $mysqli;
 $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "xylotk_chris", "-hidden-", "xylotk_database");
```

For those who keep asking for more code:

```
 include "Logged.php";
 include "Login.php";
```

In those files (Logged.php):

```
<?php

$logged = false;
if($_COOKIE['xy_user'] && $_COOKIE['xy_salt']){
   $xyuser = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_COOKIE['xy_user']);
   $xysalt = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_COOKIE['xy_salt']);
   $usrquery = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM `Accounts` WHERE `Salt`='$xysalt'");
   $usr = $usrquery->fetch_array();
   if($usr != 0){
      if(hash("sha512", $usr['Username']) == $xyuser){
         $logged = true;
    }
  } 
}

?>
```

And In Login.php:

```
<?php

if($_POST['Login']){
   if($_POST['existUsername'] && $_POST['existPassword']){

      $Username = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['existUsername']);
      $Password = $mysqli->real_escape_string(hash("sha512", $_POST['existPassword']));

      $userquery = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM `Accounts` WHERE `Username`='$Username'");
      $user = $userquery->fetch_array();
      if($user == '0'){

            die('<div class="box boxerror">That username does not exist. You can still <a href="/Login/Register.php">register <b>' . $Username . '</b></a>. <a href="/" class="btn btn-danger">Go Back</a></div>');

      }
      if($user['Password'] != $Password){

      die('<div class="box boxerror">The password entered was incorrect. <a href="/" class="btn btn-danger">Go Back</a></div>');
      }      

      $Salt = hash("sha512", rand() . rand() . rand());
      setcookie("xy_user", hash("sha512", $Username), time() + 24 * 60 * 60, "/");
      setcookie("xy_salt", $Salt, time() + 24 * 60 * 60, "/");

      $userID = $user['ID'];     
      $mysqli->query("UPDATE `Accounts` SET `Salt`='$Salt' WHERE `ID`='$userID'") or die($mysqli->error());

      header('Location: /Dashboard');

  }else{
   die('<div class="box boxerror">You missed some fields! <a href="/" class="btn btn-danger">Go Back</a></div>');
  }
}

?>
```

Comment: Showing the relevant code would be helpful

Comment: Your update.. Does not show all necessary code.

Comment: Please show us the complete code.

Comment: Is your database server running?

Comment: That IS the complete code.

Comment: @ClassicPerson409 We can tell straight away that this is not the "complete" code, you haven't showed your query,the use of `query()` and `fetch_array()` error messages say alot

Comment: @Daryl Done... surely that's enough.

Comment: @Tom Yes. It's running fine...

Comment: What happens if you put if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: (" . $mysqli->connect_errno . ") " . $mysqli->connect_error;
} after the problem line where you create a connection?

Comment: `global $mysqli;` should come "after" `$mysqli = new mysqli...`

Comment: Can you connect to your database using the mysql console?  Can you reduce the code to a single connect ("new mysqli" that is) statement and still get the error you describe?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.connections.php

Comment: Fred -ii- has the answer, thank you Fred! It worked.

Comment: You're welcome. Glad it worked out. Marked as an answer so we can properly close the question. @ClassicPerson409

Comment: Will select your answer. If I had 15 rep, I'd +1, but nope, I haven't, time to make some RELEVANT, ACTUAL questions and answer some other questions. Thanks once again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`global $mysqli;` should come "after" `$mysqli = new mysqli`...

To explain: Since you're trying to set `$mysqli` as a global before your connection, will not work because it hasn't been assigned (`$mysqli`) therefore it's outside the variable scope.

Read the PHP manual on the subject for more information on globals

- **http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php**

Comment: Any chance you could explain why?

Comment: @ClassicPerson409 Now that's just being a bit selfish ;-)  You're not the only one who reads answers!  It's not immediately obvious why this would solve the problem so I think it would be good to have more of an explanation!

Comment: You have every right to know the reason and an explanation. @RobBaillie